# Python - Print which dunder methods were called when creating an object

Tags: python, object, oop

I came across the following code, which looks easy but was a little bit of black magic for me:

```
class FileItem(dict):
    def __init__(self, name):
        dict.__init__(self, name=name)

x = FileItem("test")
print(x)
```

`{'name': 'test'}`

The same seems to be happening when I do this:

```
print(dict.__call__(name="test"))
```

`{'name': 'test'}`

I think there also has to be at least the `__init___` method be called in the second example, right? **Is there a way to print all dunder methods used to create an Object?**

From my understanding right now it seems it is:

1. `__new__`
2. `__init__` 
   Optional: `__call__`

Can anyone help me how to actually see this in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__call__` is only indirectly part of object creation.  Your example doesn't do exactly what you think it does -- it does not call `dict.__call__`.  That would only be called if you did `x()` where `x` is a `dict` instance.

`dict` happens to be an object itself, of type `class`.  The `class` type has a `__call__` method, which allows you to write `x = dict()`.  The `class.__call__` method triggers object creation.

Object creation involves `__new__` and `__init__`.

Comment: You mean `dict.__call__` not `dict,.__class__` right? I don´t really understand why when I don´t need `__call__`, this code: `print(dict.__init__({}, name="test"))` results in "None"

Comment: Because `__init__` doesn't return anything.  `__init__` is called on an empty object once created.  It's like the `new` operator in C++.  The constructor sets things up, but doesn't do the allocation.